# How to get sorted list of files by modified date that match a certain filename and print out part of text in unix shell?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Sorry for the long title. I'm trying to basically write a script that will do a "find" and get a sorted list of all files named README and print out a section of text in them. It's an easy way for me to go to a directory which has a number of project folders and print out summaries. This is what I have so far:

```
find . -name "README" | xargs -I {} sed -n '/---/,/NOTES/p' {}
```

I can't seem to get this to be sorted by modified date. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-printf` option in `find`:

```
$ find . -name 'README' -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | sort | cut -f 2-
```